# Printing nested loops using C# PrintDocument and the PrintPage event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, printdocument

I am writing a C# WinForms app, and part of it includes generating inventory reports.  I can't print the inventory one item per line, because each inventory item may be located in more than one location.  So, the goal is to print the name of the product (and a few other details) one one line, and below it, print a list of locations where the item is located and how many should be in each location, basically like this:

```
WIDGET (ACME, INC)           PRODUCT #123435       TOTAL ON HAND: 30
    Aisle: 10              Count: 15
    Aisle: 4               Count: 6
    Aisle: 15              Count: 9

SNIPE (ACE SNIPE CO)         PRODUCT #67890        TOTAL ON HAND: 11
    Aisle: 1               Count: 4
    Aisle: 3               Count: 7
```

and so on...

The problem I'm running into is, to print this requires a loop within a loop - the outer loop is the list of products, and the inner loop is the list of locations and counts for each product.  What I can't figure out is how to cause a page break when I am inside the inner loop and hit the bottom of the page.  What needs to happen is for the printing routine to print a new page header but then pick up where it left off in the list of locations for the product it was printing.

The printing code I've written works well except I can't figure out how to catch hitting the bottom of the page to start a new page while inside the inner loop[, so the printing runs off the bottom of the page.

So the question is, when you have a *loop inside another loop while printing*, how do you check page position and start a new page that continues where you left off?  I'd be glad to provide the code I have for this so far, but I thought the explanation of the problem might be easier for people to understand and provide some guidance on.  I have been banging my head against the wall on this for a couple days, and nothing I've found anywhere on the web addresses this.

Thanks for any help that is given.

Comment: The traditional mistake is looping through the data.  Can't work, you need to loop only to count lines of text that fit the page.  Make the variables that track the item and subitem fields of the class.  Initialize them with the BeginPrint event, increment the subitem as you're ready to output a subitem.  If it incremented beyond the number of subitems then reset it back to 0 and increment the item number.  If that increments beyond the number of items then you're done.  You can now always restart the PrintPage code and continue where you left off.

Comment: Hans, post this as an answer, because it made me look at something,that worked.  I set a boolean to track whether I am still printing sub-items, a counter outside the whole loop that tracks which sub-item I'm on,  *and* I check the page position inside the inner loop.  If I am at the bottom of the page at the inner loop, I trigger HasMorePages = true and break out of the loop.  When PrintPage runs, it checks to see if the sub-items flag is set.  If so, it drops through to continue printing sub-items.  There is still another check of page position on the outer loop, but this all seems to work.